# JavaFX LineChart appears blank at high value

Tags: java, user-interface, charts, javafx, nan

Just encountered an issue with javafx.scene.chart.LineChart. When populating the chart data with Double values above 5E13 or so the series happen to disapear (see screenshot).

**Before**
[image: chart before]

**After**
[image: chart before]

Just in case: I'm adding data with the folowing code

```
chart.getData().clear();
chart.getData().add(new XYChart.Series<>("Simulation name", sim.getDataAsList()));
```

It appeared to be that upperBound property of y axis sets to NaN

```
NumberAxis axis = (NumberAxis) chart.getYAxis();
        axis.upperBoundProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                if(Double.isNaN(newValue.doubleValue())){
                    System.out.println("upperBound is NaN");
                }
            }
        });
```

Please, help anyone!

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably best if you just make a divisor and call your axis billions or something.

Otherwise you could set the range yourself and provide a formatter.

Here's a snip from NumberAxis.java

```
 /** We use these for auto ranging to pick a user friendly tick unit. We handle tick units in the range of 1e-10 to 1e+12 */
    private static final double[] TICK_UNIT_DEFAULTS = {
        1.0E-10d, ..., 5.0E12d
```